# assignee in jira workflow

Tags: jira

Should I change assignee in jira issue when I've changed it state to such that other person is supposed to work on it?
What is common approach? (please provide trustworthy source of your thoughts)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If you use JIRA as an issue tracker that shows everyone what is his duty to do, you should change the assignee to the person that should work on that issue now. As assignee are only allowed person with the permission to be assigned, so there may be edge case where someone else does take the job.

Your workflow should be reflect that. So when you assign a defect to a developer (because he is the one to fix it), and the developer has fixed it has changes the status to resolved, he should have the option to assign the issue to the responsible QM person, that has to retest the relevant part of the application before closing the bug.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen also that some users change assignee to the name of reporter, in order to ping the reporter to answer their question in a comment.

I deprecate this usage.

It may mean that your miss a workflow step (such as "Waiting for reporter"), or have a missing a filter condition in a gadget or board, or miss  notification to the reporter on issue commended/updated (or the reporter consider the notifications as spam).

Fix the above, and you will have no need to assign to reporter.

Reporter is a "customer" of the task, and unless he resolves his task by himself, he shall not be assignee.

Answer (score 2):

The "assignee" is a main person who is responsible for the issue. It's not necessary who should work on it, but the one who should manage progress on the issue.
E.g. if developer has fixed a bug, the bug reporter should test it, but it's not always possible that the reporter is available or responsible enough (it could be a customer), so then a QC person should be assigned, or maybe support desk who would contact the customer and guide through the bug fix.

Comment: When bug is fixed, how could bug reporter know that he have some new bugs to retest (withing huge amount of bugs in tracking system) if this issue will not be assigned to him? If assignee will not be changed then it will be no notification to bug reporter / tester. Isn't reasonable to assign issue feather to people who should continue to work on it, or if you don't know who should continue, to responsible person and then he will reassign to needed person?

Comment: Jira could send notifications to the reporter on each state change. A reporter could be a customer, who may have reported the bug, but never bothered about it again. In other situation, if you have dedicated QC-team, then you should assign to them. So, the assigned person is who "should", but not just "could" work with the bug till the "closed" state.